# how do get data from a created processor outside program without its original python object

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing, process-management, python-daemon

am letting users in my django python app to call a function which in turn creates a process with the multiprocessor module, but i need to let users check for the processor progress (retrieve data inside it) and status (alive or done executing) and possibly terminate it (which i found easy to do with system commands) without having access to processor object since i can't store it somewhere.
is it possible to store in database only PID of the process (or some convenient identifier) and call it later? maybe try to get informations from it and manage it.
the information if i could get it directly from the process would be much reliable rather than storing it somewhere else and retrieving it there.

the function that runs in the background as a process/daemon would be completely independent of the program and has its own data that changes overtime which i need to let users be able to check its progress.

Comment: Looks like you could benefit from something like Celery....

Comment: ok thanks ill check it out